# Landmark analysis and obtaining the least event time value after a certain time

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I have a composite outcome called `primary` that includes death, stroke, myocardial infarction, and recurrence, and its time of occurrence is called `primarydays`.
I want to do a [landmark analysis and I saw this link](https://www.emilyzabor.com/tutorials/survival_analysis_in_r_tutorial.html#Landmark_approach) but I don't want to exclude any patients. I want to exclude any event before 90 days and consider the nearest time point after that to create a new time-to-event variable. So I need to create `primary90` and `primarydays90`.

Here are my sample data and code

```
df<-read.table(text="primary    primarydays dth dthdays stroke  strokedays  mi  midays  recurrence  recurrencedays
0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
1   1   0   966 0   966 1   1   0   966
0   2   0   1525    0   2   0   2   0   2
0   2   0   1407    0   2   0   2   0   2
0   2   0   16  0   2   0   2   0   2
1   2   0   689 0   689 1   2   0   689
0   2   0   499 0   2   0   2   0   2
0   2   0   2   0   2   0   2   0   2
0   2   0   38  0   2   0   2   0   2
0   2   0   2   0   2   0   2   0   2
0   2   0   12  0   2   0   2   0   2
0   2   0   534 0   2   0   2   0   2
0   2   0   540 0   2   0   2   0   2
1   3   0   1659    0   1659    1   3   0   1659
1   3   0   1430    1   1430    0   1430    1   3
1   6   0   743 1   6   0   743 1   743
1   6   0   1121    1   6   1   1121    0   1121
1   7   0   833 0   833 1   7   0   833
1   95  1   95  0   36  0   36  0   36
1   95  1   101 1   95  0   101 0   101
1   95  0   753 0   753 1   95  0   753
1   96  0   879 1   96  0   879 0   879
0   96  0   128 0   96  0   96  0   96
0   97  0   1060    0   97  0   97  0   97
0   98  0   98  0   98  0   98  0   98
0   100 0   185 0   100 0   100 0   100
1   101 0   554 0   554 0   101 0   554
1   102 0   565 0   565 1   102 0   565
1   102 0   1331    0   1331    0   1331    1   102
1   102 0   1285    1   102 0   1285    0   1285", sep="\t", header=T)

#I tried to add ">90" in the code but I am sure that it should be modified:
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(primary90 = pmax(dth    , stroke    ,   mi, recurrence, na.rm=T) >90)->df ;df
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(primary90days = pmin(dthdays    , strokedays    ,   midays, recurrencedays, na.rm=T)>90 )->df ;df
```

I can try sas as well but still struggling with the proper code.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.